# How to find the job log of ready state mainframe job?

Tags: cobol, mainframe, zos

I'm Using CA WA Workstation for monitoring mainframe jobs when I received an overdue alert for a job.  I attempted to check the job log on the Mainframe.

Using CA Workstation I tried to browse sarpage for finding job log. But I didn't get anything.  Rather, I got a message saying `No SYSOUT selected`.

I'm unsure on how to check the job log. Can some one please assist on how to check job log of ready state mainFrame Job?

Answer (score 2):

According to [CA docs](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/intelligent-automation/ca-workload-automation-de/12-2/monitoring/monitoring-and-controlling-jobs/jobs-in-active-applications/time-dependency/overdue-jobs-monitoring.html): "A job can become overdue if the job is late starting, the job is late completing, or the job exceeds its maximum execution time."

- If the job is late starting, it might be waiting for some other pre-requisite  so you should be able to see it on CA WA Workstation but there won't be a job log yet, since the job didn't start.
- If the job is late completing or exceeded its maximum execution time, it might still be running when you get the Overdue alert. In that case, you can try using SDSF on the Mainframe, or a similar tool, to check the ST or DA panels and filter by that jobname, to check its status. For example with the command:

  PRE JOBNAME;OWNER *

Replacing JOBNAME with the job you want to check. The OWNER * command will make sure you're not looking for a particular owner.

If by sarpage you mean CA-View, it could be that the job did not finish running yet. Usually the job log is only captured by CA-View once the job is complete, so again in this case you need to use SDSF or a similar tool (like IOF, EJES) to see the jobs currently running on the system.